# Cannot run mod_wsgi correctly in the docker container in Ubuntu VM

Tags: django, docker, apache, mod-wsgi

First, I installed Docker v4.20.1 in my Windows 10.

I can run the web app successfully on my windows docker container environment. But when I try to pull my image and run in the Ubuntu VM(22.04), it fails. The configuration of Apache2 and file structure are the same.

If I run the django testing server by:

```
python /usr/src/app/caravan/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It can run sucessfully and browse the page(port: 8000).
[image]

But If I try to browse the page which is handled by apache(port: 80). It fails and shows up "Internal Server Error"(500)
[image]

I have checked the mod_wsgi package, it's installed and I do enable it:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

[image]

Here is the apache2 confiuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin xxx@gmail.com

    <Directory /usr/src/app/caravan/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /usr/src/app/caravan>
        AddHandler wsgi-script .py
        Options +ExecCGI
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    # Static path
    Alias /caravan/static/ /usr/src/app/caravan/static/

    # wsgi settings
    WSGIDaemonProcess site_caravan python-path=/usr/src/app/caravan:/home/ubuntu/my_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages
    WSGIScriptAlias /caravan /usr/src/app/caravan/caravan/wsgi.py process-group=site_caravan application-group=%{GLOBAL}
</VirtualHost>
```

And docker status:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                                                          NAMES
f7e9e00d653a   phpmyadmin   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 hours ago   Up 2 hours   8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp, :::8080->80/tcp                                phpmyadmin
14c291e12362   web          "./entrypoint.sh"        3 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   web
d71ffa8be50a   db           "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 hours ago   Up 2 hours   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, :::3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                           db
```

And the mod_wsgi.so do exist and loaded.
[image]

[image]

I really don't know why this error happened...
Because the environment of my Windows docker container and Ubuntu VM docker container are completely the same.
Please help! if any one knows why. Many thanks!!

---

Answer (score 0):

okay... I finally knows why. Because there is a permission issue when the web app trying to write logs, and it fails.
[image]

After I run the chmod 777 to the log file, then it works correctly now.